# Why is the menu(mobile) and footer(desktop and mobile) not working in the index page while it's perfectly fine in other pages?

Tags: html, css, web

[image: Mobile Menu]
[image: Home Footer][image: Mobile Menu not working]

GitHub Link: https://github.com/krshnndu/ICHSP-Website

Please look over the index.html and main.css.

The problem is with the menu hamburger not working including the footer of the index page.

The current predicament involves the non-responsive behavior of the menu hamburger icon and an unyielding footer on the index page of a website. These glitches, though seemingly trivial, carry the potential to significantly disrupt user interaction and impair the overall functionality of the site.

The menu hamburger, a staple in contemporary web design, serves as a gateway to critical navigation elements. Its unresponsiveness obstructs users from accessing key sections, introducing frustration and impeding the seamless exploration of the website's features.

Simultaneously, the uncooperative footer on the index page thwarts users' attempts to retrieve vital information, access links, and engage with contact details. This oversight not only erodes user confidence but also deprives them of a persistent anchor point for reference.

These issues may emanate from a variety of sources, including JavaScript anomalies, CSS clashes, or backend misconfigurations. A thorough examination of the website's underlying code is essential to accurately diagnose and effectively rectify these issues.

In essence, these seemingly inconsequential bugs harbor the potential to create substantial usability barriers. A fluid and user-friendly browsing experience stands as a cornerstone for user satisfaction and retention. Swiftly addressing these concerns ensures unobstructed navigation, granting users access to pivotal information and nurturing a positive and enduring perception of the website.